# How can I get all directories that include more than one file with specific extension?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get directories names of those which contain more than one file with .tf extension.
Supposing this directory:

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── README.md
│   └── diagram.png
├── project
│   └── main.py
├── Makefile
├── terraform
│   ├── environments
│   │   ├── prod
│   │   │   └── main.tf
│   │   └── staging
│   │       └── main.tf
│   └── module
│       ├── ecs.tf
│       ├── rds.tf
│       ├── s3.tf
│       ├── security_group.tf
│       ├── sqs.tf
│       └── variable.tf
├── tests
|   └── test_main.py
└── .terraform
    └── ignore_me.tf
```

I expect **terraform/module** as a result.
I tried all solutions at https://superuser.com/questions/899347/find-directories-that-contain-more-than-one-file-of-the-same-extension but nothing worked as expected.

Comment: Can you please specify what solution you have tried and what is exactly not working?

Comment: I tried this: 'find . -type f -iname '*.txt' | sort | uniq -cd > result.txt' and got no results

Answer (score 0):

Those solution to that [link](https://superuser.com/questions/899347/find-directories-that-contain-more-than-one-file-of-the-same-extension) almost have done what you wanted but
you could try something like this.

```
find . -type d -exec bash -O nullglob -c 'a=("$1"/*.tf); (( ${#a[@]} > 1 ))' bash {} \; -print
```

---

The accepted answer in that [link](https://superuser.com/questions/899347/find-directories-that-contain-more-than-one-file-of-the-same-extension), just remove the `-c`, should give you the expected output.

---

See:

- [How can I check if a directory is empty or not](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004)
- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Answer (score 0):

In pure `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar dotglob

for dir in ./ **/; do
    tf_files=("$dir"*.tf)
    (( ${#tf_files[*]} > 1 )) && echo "${dir%?}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here is one that filters using `awk`

```
$ find /path/to/root -type d -printf "\0%p\001" -o -type f -iname '*.tf' -printf 'c' | awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\0";FS="\001"}(length($2)>1){print $1}'
```

The idea is to build a set of records of two fields.

- The record separator is the null character `\0`
- The field separator is the one-character `\001`
  This is to avoid problems with special filenames.

The `find` command will then print the directory name in the first field and fill the second field with the character `c` for every matching file. If we would use newlines and spaces, it would look like

```
dir1 c
dir2 cc
dir3
dir4 cccc
```

The `awk` code is then just filtering the results based on the amount of characters in the second column.